# My Blender Game Appears Gray

Tags: game-engine

I was making a zombie survival game in the Blender Game Engine that was working perfectly. After Adding a few properties to the guns to give them recoil and adding level of detail to an object the game only appears as a gray color which is my world color. Whenever I press P the only thing I can see is the "hud" overlay scene. I don't know what I did wrong but it would be nice if someone could help me fix this mistake and help me figure out what caused it so that it never happens again.

Here are the links:

Working Game: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5LVYjOK5wy6ZjR3NWZ0YjVvZ0k

Broken Game: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5LVYjOK5wy6Q3VvaDFkdkR0azg